# What is the benefit to get votes on comment of a post?

Tags: discussion, comments

I have got 1 on comment so will it be effect on any where in my profile ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vote on comment means that the comment is very usefully to this post and it makes additional hight to other users.

**It is just a highlighting process on a comment**

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what Amit said, there are 3 badges that involve comments:

- [Tumbleweed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed)
- [Commentator](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges/31/commentator)
- [Pundit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit)